# What are some SQL queries for "one-to-many" meta data filtering?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, one-to-many

I've been away from writing SQL for a while now, I am trying to find an easier solution to the following, the below works, but is there an easier, more optimized solution?

```
SELECT `application`.*, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `application_tags`.`tag` ) AS tags
FROM (`application`)
LEFT JOIN `application_tags` 
    ON `application_tags`.`application_id` = `application`.`id` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM `application_tags` 
    WHERE `application_tags`.`application_id` = `application`.`id`
    AND `application_tags`.`tag` = 'trashed'
)
GROUP BY `application`.`id`
ORDER BY `application`.`created` DESC
LIMIT 25
```

The table structure looks like this:

```
application
    id
    name
    ...

application_tags
    application_id
    tag
```

I want to be able to filter `application` by tags (meta data) set in `application_tags`. This is easy enough when trying to do direct matches, such as `application_tags.tag = 'trashed'`:

```
SELECT `application`.*, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `application_tags`.`tag` ) AS tags
FROM (`application`)
INNER JOIN `job` 
    ON `job`.`id` = `application`.`job_id` 
    AND job.account_id = 1
LEFT JOIN `application_tags` 
    ON `application_tags`.`application_id` = `application`.`id` 
WHERE `application_tags`.`tag` = 'trashed'
GROUP BY `application`.`id`
ORDER BY `application`.`created` DESC
LIMIT 25
```

But not so easy when trying to negate the search e.g. `application_tags.tag != 'trashed'` (considering the one-to-many relationship that `application_tags` has to `application`)

Negating the search does not work properly when there are many `application_tags` for a single `application` e.g. `trashed, read, archived` etc.

Can this be done without the subquery?
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You have a fixed query and filter after in the application level. Is this required ? Personnally I would build a dynamic query in the app and filter the data in pure sql.

Comment: I would like to leverage all I can from MySQL, so preferably I'd like to do all the filter there (I don't want to pull out anymore data than i need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joins can have additional conditions in the on clause. Take advantage of that and use inner join for an included attribute and left join for an excluded attribute.
Also table aliases will help you shorten your query and allow you to include the same table more than once.

```
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT t.`tag` ) AS tags
FROM `application` a
LEFT JOIN `application_tags` t ON t.`application_id` = a.`id` -- this join is for group_concat
INNER JOIN `application_tags` t1 ON t1.`application_id` = a.`id` AND t1.`tag` = 'read' -- this join is for an included attribute
LEFT JOIN `application_tags` t2 ON t2.`application_id` = a.`id` AND t2.`tag` = 'trashed' -- this join is for an excluded attribute
WHERE t2.tag is null -- this is required to exclude all rows that matched trashed
GROUP BY a.`id`
ORDER BY a.`created` DESC
```

This allows you to combine many search terms both 'has attribute' and 'has not attribute'.

About efficiency : the order in which the joins are executed are important, but I don't know if the order they appear in the statement make a difference. This depends on how mysql optimizes the query.